# Tips for converting GMPL to OPL

Tags: cplex, glpk, timetable

I've spent some time coding a Large Scale Time Tabling problem as a project using the GMPL language, generating .lp files and solving them with CBC.

Then i started using CPLEX Interactive solver to obtain faster results while solving the .lp file. But then, looking for a more dynamic language and an IDE that would easily let me link my model with external files and also let me customize the output file i decided to move my entire code to ILOG CPLEX optimization suite, using OPL.

As soon as i decided to to this, some problems popped up.

The first step that i took was trying to move a small instance of my model to OPL. This instance is based on sets and subsets. For example, i need to declare a group of "primitive" sets that later, are going to get mixed into subsets. So, let's say i want to enter all teachers, subjects and courses sets, so, it would look something like this:

```
set TEACHER : = x,y,z;
set SUBJECTS : = a,b,c;
set COURSES : = i,j,k;
```

And after that, i can create a subset that is going to link a teacher with each of the subjects and courses that this teachers is going to have during the semester:

```
set TEACHER_SUBJECTS_COURSES within {TEACHER, SUBJECTS, COURSES};
set TEACHER_SUBJECTS_COURSES := (x,a,i) (y,b,c,) (z,c,k);
```

Once i declared everything i need, i can declare a variable, that will be 1 if a certain instance of indexes is choosed for the solution, and 0 otherwise:

```
var x{t in TEACHER, d in DAY, (l,s) in LECTURE_SHIFT, (t,s,c)in TEACHER_SUBJECTS_CLASS}, binary;
```

Then every required constraint can be coded following the same idea.
This way of building the model is helpful because it  doesn't take in consideration every possible combination of indexes, it only works with every possible instance that can actually happen in my institution. The idead is that every variable containing teacher "x" is only going to take in consideration subjects and courses that are linked to teacher "x".

My question is, how can i create this kind of "link" between two sets, or how can i create a subset (or subtuple) that has two primitive sets as source in CPLEX OPL?

Comment: Did you see the examples? <installation_path>\opl\examples\opl\BasketballScheduling Maybe this could help

Comment: Thanks for aswering. Since I asked this question, the project became larger. Today I'm using python + django + postgresql to implement a web UI and I still use cplex to solve the problem. But I appreciate you taking some time to guide me, even after a long time. And yes, if I took some time to read and understand the examples I probably would not have asked this!

Comment: thanks to you for answering, I came to this question looking answering my own question, so I commented this for future readers :D

Answer (score 0):

Create a tuple to represent a combination of Teacher, Subject and Course. Then build sets of those tuples for the valid combinations.